# Save Outlook.MailItem Async?

Tags: c#, com, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption, addin-express

Is there any way to save an `Outlook.MailItem` as a `.msg` file in an asynchronous way?

I'm using:

```
MailItem.SaveAs("path", Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG);
```

But it's slow.

Answer (score 3):

Not using the Outlook Object Model - you cannot use a secondary thread inside the outlook.exe address space (COM addin): Outlook will raise an exception. If you do that from an external applications, all calls to OOM will be marshaled to the primary Outlook thread anyway.

Since you tagged your question as outlook-redemption, Redemption can do that - from your addin, store the value of the `Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT` in a variable as well as the `MailItem.EntryID` property. On the secondary thread, create an instance of the `RDOSession` object (that will initialize the MAPI system), set its `MAPIOBJECT` property to the value saved on the primary thread, call `RDOSession.GetMessageFromID,` then call `RDOMail.SaveAs`.